# Is past continuous a valid solution here

Tags: future-constructions

Mary was one of 185 passengers on a British Airways flight to Warsaw. She was feeling very excited when she got on the plane at Gatwick Airport. She had been waiting
a long time for this day. She **would finally leave/finally
left/was finally going to leave** (FINALLY LEAVE) England to start her new job in the
eastern European capital.

https://www.english-practice.at/b1/grammar/tenses/t-040-narrative-tenses.pdf

why not she was finally leaving, I think that is a valid solution (this is what she was doing , I think the going to solution is not very good we are talking here of an arrangement it is more than an  idea it is the realisation  of the idea .

Am I right?

Comment: I would use _was finally leaving_ in this context.

Comment: ...or ***was finally going to leave*** - it's just an almost meaningless stylistic choice which *exact* continuous form to use, but it should at least *be* a continuous form, to maintain consistency with preceding ***had been waiting***.